# why is array not getting formed?

Tags: c++, arrays, constants

Why is it that when I define an `array of floats` like :

```
const int i[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
float f[i[3]]; // Illegal
```

outside any function (i.e in global), it is illegal to do so.
while if I do the same thing inside any function (including main() ) like:

```
void f() {
    const int i[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    float f[i[3]];
    cout << sizeof(f);
}

main()
{
    f();
}
```

then everything works fine and it outputs the size as 16 successfully.
why is this difference ? Is it because of the change in the storage location from static (initially) to the stack ?

(PS: I know that in C++ an array can not be defined using a variable whose value is not known at the compile time, BUT still, then how is it working in the function ? )

Comment: There is no difference with MSCV. The compiler reports error C2057 "expected constant expression" in both cases.

Comment: But my compiler shows no error when I use it inside the function !

Comment: this is a g++ extension from c99

Comment: @JoelFalcou_ what is this c99 ?

Comment: @cirronimbo [c99](https://www.google.com/?q=c99)

Comment: @PeterWood: Yeah I just did that :) thnks anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, if you don't specify strict standard compliance, compilers often allow C features to be used in C++ (and vice versa). Both GCC and Clang allow such a C99 feature, namely VLAs, to be used by default. (Visual Studio, OTOH, does not support VLAs even in C mode.) Note, however, that VLAs can be defined only in block scope.

> **6.7.6.2 Array declarators**
>
> 2 If an identifier is declared as having a variably modified type, it shall be an ordinary
> identifier (as defined in 6.2.3), have no linkage, and have either block scope or function
> prototype scope. If an identifier is declared to be an object with static or thread storage
> duration, it shall not have a variable length array type.

So, a global VLA does not work in C++ (with lax compiler settings) whereas a function local VLA does.

Try compiling the following

```
$ cat float.cpp
int main() {
  int i = 2;
  const float f[i] = { 1, 2 };
}
```

with `g++ -std=c++98 -Wall -ansi -pedantic float.cpp` and you'd get something like:

```
float.cpp: In function 'int main()':
float.cpp:3:18: warning: ISO C++ forbids variable length array 'f' [-Wvla]
float.cpp:3:29: error: variable-sized object 'f' may not be initialized
float.cpp:3:15: warning: unused variable 'f' [-Wunused-variable]
```

Comment: Sorry but I didnt actually get what is written in "6.7.6.2 Array declarators" especially the last line. :(

Comment: @cirronimbo: Note the first, which is of interest to us, which says that VLAs cannot have linkage. The rest are some more fine-tuning (standardese).

Answer (score 2):

C++11 allow this :

```
#include <iostream>

constexpr int i[] = {1,2,3,4};
float k[i[2]];

int main()
{
  std::cout << sizeof(k) << "\n";
}
```

and it'll be well formed.

As for the initial question, this is probably a G++ extension.

Comment: When I compile this, the compiler is showing an error : "expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before 'int'"

Comment: you need to use a C++11 compiler, aka g++ using --std=c++0x option